# Append a value to result if the value is greater than or less than zero

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, vb6

i need to add 10 zeros(00000000,00) to a value if the value is greater than 0 and -0 if it is less than zero

Comment: what does this currently display?  "000000000,00" has 11 zeroes

Comment: why do you want this ? ... we can help you better when we understand what you are trying to do

Comment: please post some code of what you tried so far .. edit your post to do so

Answer (score 2):

For totals < 0 you need to remove the sign before appending `-0`

```
IIf(Sum(profit) - Sum(loss) > 0,
    Sum(profit) - Sum(loss) & "0000000000,00",
    "-0" & abs(Sum(profit) - Sum(loss))) AS cost
```

You probably also need to decide what to do if the result is 0, currently you will get `-00`

Comment: Use `& ",0000000000,00",` ?

Comment: So *leading* zeros now?

Comment: i gave an example it should split on every 10th value clear example eg:1000234567,890000000000,00

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but it might be something of the following ?

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim lngVal As Long
  lngVal = Val(Text1.Text)
  Print Format$(lngVal, "0000000000;-0000000000")
End Sub
```